# Drag & Drop in JavaFX table?

Tags: drag-and-drop, javafx-2

I am using a JavaFX 2 table for some kind of playlist and I want to be able to drag & drop rows in the table, e.g. drag row 3 before row 2, like the drag & drop stuff you know from the playlists in typical media players like e.g. Winamp, AIMP...

Is that possible? Any code samples for that? Thank you very much!

Comment: you can try to write `CustomCellFactory` for your table. Override `onDragStart` event there to remember index of dragged row and in `onDragEnd` event switch rows in items list.

Answer (score 7):

try this one :)

```
@FXML
TableView<String> tableView;
private  ObservableList<String> tableContent = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

//...

tableView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { //click
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    if(event.getClickCount()==2){ // double click

                        String selected =   tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                        if(selected !=null){
                            System.out.println("select : "+selected);
                           ...
                        }
                    }
            }
    });

tableView.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { //drag
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            // drag was detected, start drag-and-drop gesture
            String selected = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            if(selected !=null){

                Dragboard db = tableView.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
                ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                content.putString(selected);
                db.setContent(content);
                event.consume(); 
            }
        }
    });

tableView.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                // data is dragged over the target 
                Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
                if (event.getDragboard().hasString()){
                    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
                }
                event.consume();
            }
        });

tableView.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
                boolean success = false;
                if (event.getDragboard().hasString()) {            

                    String text = db.getString();
                    tableContent.add(text);
                    tableView.setItems(tableContent);
                    success = true;
                }
                event.setDropCompleted(success);
                event.consume();
            } 
        });
```

Comment: cool, a new member posting a reply as first post! welcome here! unfortunately I am not using java fx anymore, but I appreciate your reply and it's likely a great answer for the archive here / other users :-)

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! :) 
What are you using nowadays?

Comment: I think he is using C# wpf frameWork