# Drag and Drop of individual cells JAVAFX

Tags: javafx-8

So I'm looking for some guidance I'm working on a JavaFX version 8, project where I want to be able to move/DragDrop a String content of an individual cell from a Tableview, over to another cell, in another TableView so if anyone has any tips or have done this in another project before and would share their knowledge it would be much appreciated

Comment: Hello :) Have you read [this request on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353576/drag-drop-in-javafx-table?rq=1)?

Comment: @0009laH No I haven't, but will for sure give it a look, thanks alot